# Is there a way to check date dynamically in eloqua?

Tags: date, email, eloqua

Context: I am using Microsoft Dynamics (CRM) and Eloqua to send email campaigns.  I have a date field in CRM that I want to check against in Eloqua for a specific campaign.  This campaign needs to check to see if the date field is `<= today's date + 90 days`.  I am using the campaign UI in Eloqua, not doing anything programmatically at this point.

- I have tried using the Compare Custom Object Fields decision in Eloqua by finding the date field, setting the comparator to `dynamically on or before`, and I want to make the compared value `Today + 90 days`.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this in this type of Decision object because the only options I have to compare the date field to are `Yesterday`, `Today`, or `Tomorrow`.  See image below: [image]
- I have also tried to use the Compare Date Decision object, but there is no dynamic comparison, just hard-coded date options.
- The last thing I tried was a Wait step, but that only waits a hard-coded number of days rather than checking dynamically.

Has anyone run into this issue or know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to find an Eloqua Date App to download that adds a Date Decision step to the program builder which allowed us more flexibility with comparing dates in a custom range.

[image: Date Decision App - Details]